# Python4Delphi GetIt Demos aren't working in Delphi 12

Tags: python, delphi, delphi-12-athens, python4delphi

I just downloaded Python4Delphi from getIt and after it finished installing, it opened the demos for me.

When I run the demos, I just keep getting errors:

> Error 87: Could not open Dll "python33.dll"

> Python could not be properly initialized. We must quit.

My getIt installation of Python4Delphi was successful without any issues. So why does the Demos not work?

Comment: Maybe your `PATH` environment variable has grown too long, so that newly added entries are beyond the max allowed length?

Comment: @TomBrunberg How can I check?

Comment: It depends on your OS. If Win10, then the total length of the whole PATH record is about 32k (I don't have the exact value at hand now) and individual paths are limited to 260 chars, unless you have changed your system settings. For details, visit another StackExchange site: `https://superuser.com/` and search for `max path length` and you will get plenty of good Q/A.